# How do I troubleshoot Chrome crashing?

Tags: windows-vista, google-chrome

I'm running Chrome in Vista 64 and it crashes a LOT (sometimes every time I change pages).  I find it happens on almost any site, but is more common when the site has flash, and also more common when I also have FireFox running.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... sounds like Flash is the culprit, eh?

Make sure you have the latest-greatest version of Flash installed. And if that doesn't work, modify your shortcut to pass the `-disable-plugins` parameter to `chrome.exe` (and then close all Chrome windows and re-open) - this will disable Flash completely (as well as any other plugins you might have).

Comment: Thanks for this. I updated my Flash and that "seems?" to have fixed my multi-crash problem.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Flash has been implicated in all the stability issues I've had with Chrome (on XP), so I believe you're on to something there.  All I can really recommend, though, is making sure you have the latest, greatest versions of everything, and if that doesn't help, staying away from Flash.  Sorry. :(

Oh, actually, there is one thing.  If you're using Incognito mode, you might want to try without.  Sometimes it's seemed as if Flash is unhappy with it, possibly as if it causes Flash to blow out Chrome's memory usage (which might relate to the having Firefox open part of things).

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error message? Microsoft .NET Framework may have something to do with it; but that usually gives an error message something like (or exactly like):

> The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135). Click OK to terminate the application.

What more can you tell us about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Browser crashes with Windows Vista (only during  initial launch):

we have to disable **superfetch** service from Vista services:

- Start ->  Run  ->  Services.msc
- scroll down to locate **Superfetch** service
- double-click mouse on Superfetch
- choose  Startup-type to **Disbled.**
- click   **Apply**
- **Reboot**  the system

It is good to delete all the files from  `C:\Windows\Prefetch`  folder regularly. We can delete the Prefetch folder itself completely, after deleting the Prefetch\Readyboot folder.

Comment: Using Capital Alphabets won't add any difference to your answer.